# TFS merge discarded still shown in merge wizard (vsts)

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a TFS build that generates some static resources and checkin the changes into DEV.

Then, when merging from DEV to QA, the "static resources" changeset will be shown. But I don't wan't to merge these changeset because in each branch are generated.

I found "tf merge" and following the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/merge-command?view=vsts) at the end of the build I execute a script like:

> **tf merge** $/DEV/Product/source_branch/static/
>   $/DEV/Product/target_branch/  **/discard /recursive**

After that I tried to do a checkin, but there are no pending changes (as I'm discarding all). Don't do a checkin, but then in the merge wizard on Visual Studio I can see the changeset from DEV.

What I'm doing wrong? **I want to don't see the discarded changesets when I merge form DEV to QA in Visual Studio**

Comment: If they're generated automatically by the build process, why put them in source control at all? Use the same generation method in your local build process and exclude the generated stuff from source control entirely.

Comment: because then are used for whatever for other teams.